# Run certain commands upon activation of conda environment

Tags: shell, conda

When I run `conda activate myenv`, I'd like to do certain other things to set up my working environment (like `cd` into the right directory, load a couple other things outside conda, add a specific path to the `PYTHONPATH`, etc). Is there a way to do this? A shell script inside the files for `myenv` that I can add commands to? I went looking for an `activate` script but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 4):

There is [this section of the documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux) which explains it for environemnt variables, but it also works for other commands as these files are simply `sourced` at some point during the environment activation.

Simply put the commands you want to run during activation into

```
${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d
```

make sure to evaluate `${CONDA_PREFIX}` while the env is active